# How to save a model with a child and get the saved model with child back as a response in Vapor 3

Tags: swift, vapor

I'm trying to write a controller function to insert a model with a child model at the same time and get the same JSON response in return, but filled with the data added from the database (i.e. the automatically generated id).

For the bellow simplified example the JSON request body would look like this:

```
{
    "field1": "blabla",
    "subContent": {
        "field2": "lalala"
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the following response:

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "field1": "blabla",
    "subContent": {
        "id": 44,
        "field2": "lalala"
    }
}
```

The below code unfortunately doesn't compile, the error message says "Cannot convert expression of type 'EventLoopFuture' to return type 'Response'. This occurs on line

```
return subModel.create(on: req).flatMap { savedSubModel ->
```

Here's the code:

```
struct MainContent: Content {
    var id: UUID?
    var field1: String
    var subContent: SubContent
}

struct SubContent: Content {
    var id: UUID?
    var field2: String
}

final class Controller {
    func create(_ req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<Response> {
        return try req.content.decode(MainContent.self).map { request in
            let subModel = SubModel(
                field2: request.subContent.field2
            )
            return subModel.create(on: req).flatMap { savedSubModel -> EventLoopFuture<Response> in
                let mainModel = mainModel(
                    subModelId: savedSubModel.id!,
                    field1: request.field1
                )
                return mainModel.create(on: req).flatMap { savedMainModel -> EventLoopFuture<Response> in
                    let content = MainContent(
                        id: savedMainModel.id,
                        field1: savedMainModel.field1,
                        subContent: SubContent(
                            id: savedSubContent.id,
                            field2: savedSubContent.field2
                        )
                    )
                    return content.encode(status: .created, for: req)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you're in the beginning I'd suggest to switch to Vapor4 cause it is stable in its core cause it is based on NIO2 which is in release for a long time already.

Comment: I actually started trying Vapor 4, but the current version doesn't even compile.

Comment: It is compile but Fluent4 requires Swift 5.2 so if you want to use it with Fluent you have to either install the latest beta Xcode or just download Swift 5.2 from swift.org and then you will be able to choose it in your current version of Xcode. Or another option is to use my Bridges lib with SwifQL without Fluent. https://github.com/SwifQL/Bridges But it is for people who want to deal with SQL.

Comment: I tried it last week using the latest version of XCode and followed the guides in the beta docs. All framework libraries could be downloaded, but upon building I got a couple of compile errors in the frameworks (I think it was Fluent 2.0). So I decided to go back to a stable release. I hope there will be some good tutorials to upgrade from V3 to V4.

Comment: Have you ensured that you was on Swift 5.2? Because the latest non-beta Xcode from the AppStore is on Swift 5.1.3 and you need a beta Xcode from developer portal instead or download Swift 5.2 from swift.org

Comment: Anyway find me on the Discord as imike#3049 I'd love to help

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware that Swift 5.2 is currently only on the beta version of XCode. Maybe I will try again. But as the docs for Vapor 4 aren't finished yet and I'm totally new to Vapor, I guess is better to stay on version 3 for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```swift
struct MainContent: Content {
    var id: UUID?
    var field1: String
    var subContent: SubContent
}

struct SubContent: Content {
    var id: UUID?
    var field2: String
}

final class Controller {
    func create(_ req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<Response> {
        return try req.content.decode(MainContent.self).flatMap { request in
            let subModel = SubModel(
                field2: payload.subContent.field2
            )
            return subModel.create(on: req)
        }.flatMap { savedSubModel in
            let mainModel = mainModel(
                subModelId: try savedSubModel.requireID(),
                field1: request.field1
            )
            return mainModel.create(on: req).flatMap { savedMainModel in
                let content = MainContent(
                    id: try savedMainModel.requireID(),
                    field1: savedMainModel.field1,
                    subContent: SubContent(
                        id: try savedSubModel.requireID(),
                        field2: savedSubModel.field2
                    )
                )
                return content.encode(status: .created, for: req)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're genius! Thanks for this.